# jquery file upload plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, file-upload

i have to use the jquery file upload plugin from this [link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuery-File-Upload). What I am looking for is some basic syntax to call this plugin, perform start, upload, delete etc. operations. The wiki is not very helpful which is why i am posting this question here. Please help.

Comment: What is teh Backend you use? There are HowTos for serveral Frameworks like Zend/Symfony etc.tt.

Comment: Are you asking about how to configure the HTML page to do these operations, or how to handle these operations on the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at their documentation page? Yes the jquery page is light on details, but you can find much more information [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup).

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the documentation but it doesn't have what i am looking for!